# My bibliography has 2 parts. How to get the name right?

Tags: bibliographies

I'm using the basic class article/scrartcl. I have a (manually created) bibliography which consists of 2 parts. I am able to add the different parts under different names into the TOC by

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Primärliteratur}
\begin{thebibliography}
...
\end{thebibliography}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Internetquellen}
\begin{thebibliography}
...
\end{thebibliography}
```

but I get the heading "Literatur" on both parts of the bibliography-section of course.
If I try to insert
    \renewcommand{\bibname}{Internetquellen}

before the second thebibliography-environment that doesn't help.
What can I do to get 2 different headers for the bibliography?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `\refname`; moreover, `\addcontentsline` should go inside the `thebibliography` environment:

```
\renewcommand{\refname}{Primärliteratur}
\begin{thebibliography}{99}% <-- fix the number
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Primärliteratur}
...
\end{thebibliography}

\renewcommand{\refname}{Internetquellen}
\begin{thebibliography}{99}% <-- fix the number
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Internetquellen}
...
\end{thebibliography}
```

How do I know `\refname` instead of `\bibname`? Because in `ngermanb.ldf` I find “Literatur” associated to `\refname`, while the default value for `\bibname` is “Literaturverzeichnis”.

The `article` class uses `\refname`, while the `report` and `book` class use `\bibname`.

Don't forget the mandatory argument to `\begin{thebibliography}`.

Comment: Great! \refname did the trick! Thanks a lot!